# getting modelstate false when no value is selected from dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**I am having two roles in my websites**:**Customer and Vendor**

Now when vendor is doing registeration then i am providing option for **selecting category in the from of dropdownlist control**.Category can be as follows:**Plumber,Electrical,Tailor,Carpenter** etc...

**This Category are loaded in the dropdownlist from which Vendor can select appropriate category.**

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select City")]
    [DataMember]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
```

i have given radio button option for Vendor and Customer on my registration page.so if user is selecting vendor then i am displaying category dropdownlist and if user is selecting customer then i am not displaying this dropdown.

So when user submits the form this is what i am doing on my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public  ActionResult Registration(UserDetailsModel _userDetails)
    {
       if(ModelState.IsValid)
       {
       }
       else
       {
           //Error..
       }
    }
```

My Model:

```
public class UserDetailsModel
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Name")]
        [DataMember]
        public string Fullname { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select City")]
        [DataMember]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    }
```

**So problem is when user is selecting customer option then i am getting modelstate as false as because categoryid will be null in case of customer(as because i am not showing category dropdown to customer)**.

So How do i resolve this??

Any Help....

Comment: You could look at using [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` attribute or one of their other attributes which allow conditional validation based on another property.

Comment: but how do i will check this for customer or for vendor and where??

Comment: You haven't even shown you model or what the property associated with Vendor/Customer is, but there are various versions of `[RequiredIf]`, for example if its `bool IsVendor` then you could use `RequiredIfTrue("IsVendor")]` which would only add the error if your selected "Vendor" - you need to go through the documentation and look at some examples.

Comment: Please see my Edited question.i am having only 1 model for both customer and vendor.

Comment: You haven't shown the property for  determining if the user is a Vendor or Customer (the one you use to render the radio buttons)

Comment: actually i dont have taken any property for that to differentiate between customer and vendor as because i will get 0 in Categoryid in case of customer and any value(except 0) in case of vendor.so i didnt see any need for that.i think i have wrongly designed my model.right???

Comment: Yes, you need to rethink your design. And when you say you are _not showing category dropdown to customer_ do you mean that you hide/disable the dropdownlist depending on which radio button is selected?

Comment: Yup i am Hiding my Dropdown(not disabling) when Customer radio button is selected and displaying dropdown when Vendor Radio button is selected

Comment: Then you need to add property to your model so you can use a `[RequiredIf]` attribute.

Comment: can you show me how my model design should be with data annotation please if you are not busy???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property to your model to indicate if the user is a Customer or Vendor and apply the [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` attribute. If the value of the radio button for `UserType` is "Vendor", then an error will be displayed if no "City" has been selected.

```
public class UserDetailsModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserType { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Name")]
    [Display(Name = "Full name")]
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    [RequiredIf("UserType", "Vendor", ErrorMessage = "Please Select City")]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public SelectList CityList { get; set; } // suggest this rather than ViewBag
}
```

Then in the view

```
@model UserDetailsModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UserType, "Customer", new { id = "customer" })
  @Html.Label("customer")
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UserType, "Vendor", new { id = "vendor" })
  @Html.Label("vendor")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserType)

  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)

  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CategoryId)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, Model.CityList, "-Please select-")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CategoryId)

  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: thank you so much sir.keep helping like this.thank u once again

Comment: sir one last question.can i ask you??

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: sir i am learning angular js and so i have created 1 demo project on angular js with MVC which contains crud operation(insert,update and delete).so i just want to post link of my dropbox onstackoverflow which contain my demo project to download and some problem which i am facing in my project.so can i post question like this?

Comment: No, your question needs to include the relevant code relating to the problem. If you just include a link, it will be voted down and closed (and its unlikely anyone will look at it anyway)

Comment: but i cant post the whole code as because its a lots of code and i dont think anyone would take care to look at that.

Comment: And they certainly would not look at it if its a link. You just need to breakdown the problem and address one issue at a time and include just the minimum code necessary to explain the problem or any errors that being thrown.

Comment: No, can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new category "none" and make it the default value. Afterwards, you can test for it...

Comment: i am having values in my dropdown as follows:0 None,1 plumber 2 Tailor etc..like this was.Can you please describe in more details of what you are trying to say.

Comment: Avoid doing this. You lose client side validation and you need to rely on a server side check, then add a model state error and return the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a default selected value for the dropdown like this-

Set selected="selected" for the option you want to be the default.

```
<option value="0" selected="selected">
None
</option>
```

This will select the default value for the control when hidden and the modelstate will be true for the dropdown field.

Comment: I have already done this:List<SelectListItem> categories = new List<SelectListItem>().ToList();categories.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Select Category", Value = "0" });

Answer (score -1):

You must change your `int` to `int?`.

so you end up with this code:

```
public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
```

this happens with all value types.

**Additional info**
The model binder will instantiate a new object when the request get to the controller, so CategoryId will be set to 0 (it cannot be null) so the Required attribute don't know if that 0 is from the request or not hence making it always valid. That's why Nullable `int?` will work.

This was working like this for years lots of people think it's by design but on MVC 6 they marked it as a bug. Here is the issue : https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1971

Comment: really try to use nullable int and if the role is vendor and `categoryid == null` do a `ModelState.AddModelError()` manually on controller before the `ModelState.IsValid`

Comment: but this would be done after my post action will be fired but i dont want to do that.Please see @ Stephen Muecke comments.